# Failing to connect to database on restart spring-jdbc, commons-dbcp,tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat6, spring-jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

If database restarts when the tomcat is up and running , re-connect fails. If tomcat is restarted everythign works fine. Is there a way where we can reconnect when the database is recovered?

Below is the code snippet:

```
<bean id="basicDataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:testOnBorrow="true" p:validationQuery="SELECT * from USERS">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>driverClassName</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>url</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>username</value>
        </property> 
        <property name="password">
            <value>password</value>
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

Comment: try setting `testOnReturn` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `testOnReturn` to `true`
[Configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/DBCP) for DBCP explained.

Snippet from the link.

```
    GenericObjectPool.addObjectToPool()
 Only calls validateObject() if 'testOnReturn' has been set. This parameter is
 passed in the pool's constructor. If the (returned) Object fails validation, it is
immediately destroyed.
```

Comment: Tried with the option you provided but did not help!